# How to Find the Number of Orders from Specific Country

Tags: magento-1.9

I tried using following method. But it's not working

```
$total = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('country_id', array('eq'=>'SA'))
->getSize();

echo '<pre>Total: ' . $total . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$total = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getShippingAddress()->getCollection() // changes it to getBillingAddress if you want to filter it from billing address
->addFieldToFilter('country_id', array('eq'=>'SA'))
->getSize();

echo '<pre>Total: ' . $total . '</pre>';
```

Let me know if you found any difficulties.

Comment: Thank you brother!

Comment: Welcome Arjun. Happy coding